# How to get rules for particular product in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I need to get the eligible cart rule for a product(Before add to cart) in magento2?

```
public function getOfferRuleId($productId)
    {
        //Get the rule id for product and list page offer notifier ajax call
        $ruleId = '';
        $customRuleIds = [];
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $rules = $this->ruleCollection->create();
        $product->setProductId($productId);
        $customRules = $this->getOfferRules();
        foreach ($customRules as $rule) {
            $customRuleIds[] = $rule->getId();
        }
        /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule */
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            try {
                if ($rule->getActions()->validate($product)) {
                    if (in_array($rule->getId(), $customRuleIds)) {
                        return $rule->getId();
                    }
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the answer...its taking whole cart rules in foreach... so it takes times to load...How to solve this

Comment: Do you need this on product page or magento event observer?

Comment: List page......